# CosmosDb filter array by property and aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb

Given the following document structure:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("..."),
  lists: [
    {
      name: 'List 1'
      meta: {
        expiresOn: 1621560318226
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'List 2'
      meta: {
        expiresOn: 1418971859555
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to get an aggregation of all the lists that have the property `expiresOn` greater than a certain timestamp but this seems to be harder than I thought. So the expected result would be:

```
[
 { name: 'List 1' }
 { name: 'List from another document' }
]
```

What I've tried is the following:

```
db.someCollection.aggregate([ 
  {
    $project: {
      lists: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$lists",
          as: "list",
          cond: { $gte: [ "$$list.meta.expiresOn", 1516620762985 ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind :'$lists'},
  { 
    $project : { 
      _id:0, 
      name: '$lists.name',
    } 
  }
])
```

When running it in CosmosDb's Mongo Shell I get `ERROR: Command aggregate failed: Unknown server error occurred when processing this request..`.

I've tried to split the aggregation into pieces and run them individually and they seem to work except the first one.

What am I doing wrong?

LE: Tried another approach, similar to the one before but this one returns empty:

```
db.clients.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$lists'},
  { 
    $match: {
      'lists.meta.expiresOn': { $gt: 1516620762985 }
    }
  },
  { 
    $project : { 
      _id:0, 
      name: '$lists.name',
    } 
  }
])
```

And on a side note ... how well such an aggregation performs? Did I mention i'm a beginner in this field? :)

Thanks!

Comment: what version of mongo db are you using?

Comment: The problem is not mongodb but cosmosdb. Just ran the same queries on mongo and everything works just fine. So this means CosmosDB is definitely not mature enough to be used in production...or at least for now. Testing MongoDB Atlas now :)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, I have an instance with version 3.6 mongo and other with 3.2, both on cosmosdb, the first one is working fine but not the second one.

Both versions in local (without cosmosdb) are working fine.